# Is there a way to equip an item in the belt and quick bag?

Tags: lies-of-p

In *Lies of P*, is there any way to equip an item in both the quick bag and the upper/lower belt? Specifically, the pulse cell — if the item is equipped in the upper belt, I can see the number of charges remaining and see the progress towards recovery. If I equip the item in the quick bag, it unequips it from the belt, and I can no longer see the charges remaining at all times.

I'd prefer to have this in the quick bag so it's always available the same way, but not being able to quantity at all times is a problem. Any other way to make the pulse cell count always visible would also work, but I didn't see anything in the menu.

Strangely, sometimes I can see the progress for recharging the cell in the empty belt slow, but this doesn't always happen. I think it's a bug and not a deliberate feature, and it's definitely not reliable.

If it matters for anything, I'm using a mouse and keyboard, not a controller.